# All $L^pL^q$ estimates for the heat equation on $\mathbb R$ (with gain of derivatives)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, linear-pde, heat-equation

[I have asked this question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4662966/what-are-all-lplq-estimates-for-the-heat-equation-with-gain-of-derivatives), but this is a better place.

---

**The heat equation and the heat kernel.**

Consider the heat equation on $\mathbb R$:
$$ \left\{\begin{aligned}u_t-\Delta u&=f\\u(0,x)&=0\quad\forall x\in\mathbb R. \end{aligned}\right. $$
It is well-known that under suitable hypotheses there exists a unique solution $u$ given by the Duhamel formula (see below). So, we consider the operator $\Gamma:=(\partial_t-\Delta)^{-1} $ which maps $f$ to the solution $u$, that is, $$ u=\Gamma f. $$
Given the heat kernel
$$ G(t,x)=\frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{1/2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}, $$
one can show that $u$ is given as a space-time convolution between $G$ and $f$:
$$ u(t,x)=\left(\Gamma f\right)(t,x)=\int_0^\infty\int_{\mathbb R^d} G(t-s,x-y)f(s,y)\,\,dyds. $$

---

**The problem.**

> **Problem.** Given $s\in[0,2]$, find all quadruples $(p,q,r,\sigma)$ such that the
> following estimate holds for all test functions $f\in\mathcal
>  D((0,\infty)\times\mathbb R)$, for some constant $C>0$: $$ \||\partial_x|^s\Gamma f
>  \|_{L^rL^\sigma}\leq C\|f\|_{L^pL^q}. \qquad (1)$$

The norm in the space $L^pL^q$ is given by
$$ \|f\|_{L^pL^q}^p:=\int_0^\infty\|f(s,\cdot)\|^p_{L^q}ds, $$
so it's the classical mixed $L^p-L^q$ norm in which you take first the $L^q$ norm in the $x$ variable and then the $L^p$ norm in the $t$ variable. The fractional derivative $|\partial_x|^s$ is defined via the Fourier transform.

Basically, the problem is to find all the 'Strichartz estimates' of the heat equation with fractional gain of derivatives. Note that this is **not** about the fractional heat equation: we simply want to prove estimates on the derivatives of the solution to the classical heat equation.

---

**Considerations and known estimates.**

By scaling considerations, one immediately finds that the coefficients must satisfy
$$ \left(\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1/2}{\sigma}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1/2}{q}\right)-1+\frac{s}{2}. \qquad (2)$$
Thus, in what follows I will always assume $(2)$. I will also assume $p\leq r$ and $q\leq\sigma$ (essentially because convolution with a given function maps $L^p$ to $L^q$ with $q\geq p$).

Preliminarly, I state without proof the following estimates for the heat kernel:
$$ \||\partial_x|^sG(t,\cdot)\|_{L_x^p}\lesssim |t|^{-\frac{1}{2}(1+s)+\frac{1}{2p}}, \quad s\geq 0,\,\,1\leq p\leq \infty. \qquad (3)$$

What I already know is the following:

1. The estimate holds in the cases
   $$ s\in\{0,1\},\quad 1\leq q\leq \sigma\leq \infty,\quad 1<p<r<\infty. $$
   This follows from a direct use of the Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality and the estimates $(3)$ for $s=0$ and $s=1$ (see [this book](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/311233584_Harmonic_analysis_method_for_nonlinear_evolution_equations_I)).
2. This is not in the book, but with the same proof, using the full range of estimates $(3)$, one covers all the cases $s\in[0,2)$ with the same conditions on $p,q,r,\sigma$ as above.
3. The estimates hold in the case $(r,\sigma)=(\infty,2)$ with $1\leq q\leq 2$. This follows by integrating the heat equation against $u$ and perform standard energy estimates.

What is left is a lot of endpoint cases (most prominently, $s=2$, $p=r$, $p=1$, and $r=\infty$).

---

**Finally, my question.**

My question is: what about the case $r=\infty$, $1<\sigma<\infty$ and $s\in(0,2)$? It seems that energy estimates do not help for the full range of exponents $(p,q)$ and work only for certain values of $\sigma$ anyway. Do you know a way to cover all cases, or a reference that covers all cases? I am reasonably sure that one can exchange the roles of $x$ and $t$ and use Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev, but that would work only for $p\leq q$.

I am especially interested in the case $(r,\sigma)=(\infty,2)$, $q=2$ for $s\in(0,2)$ (which would basically cover all other cases $(p,q)$ by Sobolev embedding), i.e.,
$$ \||\partial_x|^{2-\frac{2}{p}}\Gamma f\|_{L^\infty L^2}\lesssim \|f\|_{L^pL^2}. $$
If the case $q=2$ is too hard, $q<2$ would be well accepted. Even the case $s=1$ is not clear to me at the moment, except when $(p,q)=(2,2)$.

Besides my specific question, it would be nice to collect some references that address estimate $(1)$ in all known ranges of exponents (unless you can think of a paper which treats all these estimates at once, which would be very appreciated). So, if you have a reference for any of the remaining ranges of exponents, even for higher dimensions, that would be very appreciated.

---

**Related posts and references:**

- [A previous post with a similar question (basically the case $s=0$)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270405/strichartz-estimates-for-the-heat-equation)
- [Something about the case $s=2$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/218687/mixed-norm-estimate-for-the-heat-equation)